# Is it acceptable to hand off a job ( scraping images ) to Node.js from PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I am working on a project where I am taking a URL for a page and finding an image to represent the page. After looking at the metadata, I look to the page content and start scraping the page. This is a PHP project.

Using PHP, the getimagesize() function has a long timeout and if there are lots of images on the page, it becomes a very slow process.

I went with a solution that is a little odd, but very fast. I am looking to see if there is a better solution or if there are any glaring problems with my solution.

--- Start Solution ---

In PHP, build an array of image URLs. Connect to a socket, handled by Node.js, and pass the array of URLs to the Node.js handler. Meanwhile, have a blocking read on the PHP side, waiting for a response.

In Node.js, I get the image size / type of the images from the URLs using the 'imagesize' module. When all the jobs are finished,  write the URL of the largest image to the socket. Any error will also write to the socket before closing the socket. This is run as a daemon with the 'forever' module.

The PHP side unblocks after it reads from the socket.

--- End Solution ---

Is this an acceptable way to solve this problem? It works and on some poorly formed blogspot pages I saw 10x performance improvements. I am aware there are some threading solutions in PHP, but I am worried about the sheer number of threads for some pages.

Update:

The requirement is that this give immediate feedback, so cron jobs or queues don't fit the requirement.

Comment: Hand jobs are always acceptable ?

Answer (score 0):

If you see Performance improvements then it's acceptable way to solve your problem. I would suggest on trying [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/shell_exec) function to run your node.js process. you can pass urls as command line arguments which you can access with `process.argv` this way you will not need to keep you node.js process always running. Run it only when needed through php.

Comment: The way I understand it, Apache/PHP will have a different thread for each connection to the web server. With this way, each one of these threads would be able to create a new process. From what I understand, this doesn't take advantage of Node.js's small footprint. It is also also extremely easy to pass data over sockets, but passing data around from shell_exec is a little more complicated. I've done something similar with a Python script and I remember it was no where near as simple as just using sockets.

Comment: Another way I can think of is using queue, You create jobs from php and a queue processor in node.js will read message from queue and perform the requested job.